What is meant by BFW10 for an FET Amplifier?
I am an Electronics student and my knowledge level is quite basic. In our Circuits lab, we were instructed to design a FET amplifier with a gain of 12.
"Let \$V_{DD} = 30 V\$, \$I_D = 3mA\$. For BFW10 , \${ID}_{ss} = 20mA\$  , \$V_{GS}(off) = V_p = 8 V \$"
This was part of our design statement.
I did a basic research and found that BFW was something related to the frequency range that the transistor would work on but I could not find a clear answer.

BFW10 is the transistor type.

BFW10 is the model name of the JFET device.. Find ts datasheet from a semiconductor manufacturer. See its datasheet and you can understand its operation.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Thanks for the clarification.

A component designation like BFW 10 follows the Pro Electron system.
In their position B means silicon; F high frequency, low power; a third letter used to indicate industrial use as opposed to consumer electronics.

To add to what Andy said, found a BFW10 datasheet which is described as a JFET VHF/UHF Amplifier
The Guide to BFW10 30V N-Channel JFET [Datasheet] has some background information.
